# Model Validation or Javascript Validation? Best practice

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, validation

I have an MVC application which contains an enrollment page. On the model class:

```
public class Register
{
[Required(ErrorMessageResourceName="Name Required"), ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(ErrorMessages))]
public string Name { get; set; }
[Required(ErrorMessageResourceName="Password Required"), ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(ErrorMessages))]
public string Password1 { get; set; }
[Required(ErrorMessageResourceName="Confirm Password Required"), ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(ErrorMessages))]
public string Password2 { get; set; }
}
```

What it does is to not allow the user to register if the name, password1 or password2 is blank.

My problem is I need to add a validation to check if password1 is equal to password2. Is it good to include that validation in this class? Or do it on the .cshtml file as javascript validation?

I know it is possible both ways but I also want the best practice for creating validations.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do both. MVC has built in javascript validation. Look into `unobtrusive-validation` for MVC. It will render your attributes you've used above in javascript automatically for you.

Comment: I did some reading about unobtrusive-validation. They are both validations. Correct me if i'm wrong. The model validation is triggered on postback while that javascript validation is triggered without postback.

Comment: Correct. You do exactly as you have done above.. but the unobtrusive validation happens in Javascript on the client side automatically for you.. before a postback.

Comment: You can't go wrong in doing both. I always do both. Client side is fast and if client side fails then you have backup on the server side.

Comment: @BrendanVogt Yes, I'll do it both sides. Thanks!